# VBA Combobox Value returns "" but it's populated and selected

Tags: excel, vba, combobox

I have 2 Comboboxes in a form in Excel VBA. Both are correctly named (`pricing` and `costReport`) and both get populated with the total list of open Workbooks. Also both get preselected correctly, looking for the existence of specific strings in their values. So when I hit the Submit button, I want to check each Combobox Value and what happens is very strange.

Depending on the order of each function (`UserForm_Initialize` and `button_Click`), the results vary. Check the comments to see the detail.

```vb
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    'populate each Combobox with the list of open Workbooks
    For Each book In Workbooks
        pricing.AddItem (book.Name)
        costReport.AddItem (book.Name)
    Next

    'preselect the Value of each, depending on the presence of a specific word
    'both Comboboxes end up correctly selected
    For Each book In Workbooks
        If InStr(1, book.Name, "pricing", 1) > 0 Then
            pricing.Value = book.Name
        End If
        If InStr(1, book.Name, "cost", 1) > 0 Then
            costReport.Value = book.Name
        End If
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub button_Click()
    Dim getPricing As String
    getPricing = "-" & Me.pricing.Value & "-"
    
    Dim getCostReport As String
    getCostReport = "-" & Me.costReport.Value & "-"
    
    Debug.Print getPricing
    Debug.Print getCostReport

    'if button_Click() is put before UserForm_Initialize()
    '   getPricing prints "-correct text-"
    '   getCostReport prints "--"

    'but if button_Click() is put after UserForm_Initialize()
    '   getPricing prints "--"
    '   getCostReport prints "-correct text-"
End Sub
```

The strangest thing of all, is that if I manually select other Values (or the same ones) with my mouse cursor while executing the form, then both Values are stored correctly. Therefore I thought it could be a listener or timing issue. I tried changing the `Initialize` event to `Activate`, and I've also tried using Wait for a few seconds, none of which works.

You can see a reprex [here](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1dN0iv_g9RsfIfourzoKenk7wq70SZZ0n?usp=sharing)

Comment: String concatentation `"-" + Me.pricing.Value + "-"` has to be done with `&` sign  `"-" & Me.pricing.Value & "-"` the `+` is for adding numbers only!

Comment: I just adjusted it but the problem hasnt changed.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ `msgbox "4" + "2"`

Comment: @GSerg `msgbox "4" + 2`: I recommend not to use `+` for concatentation because you easily run into such issues especially because VBA does allow variables of type `Variant`. So you might not know which types you have there. `msgbox "4" + myVar` if `myVar` is `Variant Long = 2` you get `6` but if it is `Variant String = "2"` you get `42`. So highly not recommended to concatenate with `+`!

Comment: @Pᴇʜ Neither do I recommend using it. But it can be used, it's in the language, and it's wrong to say that it works for adding numbers only.

Comment: @federomano The order of subs bears no significance. I cannot reproduce your issue with the code you've posted.

Comment: @GSerg I don't trust it. Even more because [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/plus-operator) does not reflect the actual behaviour of the + operator. It says *"One expression is a String and the other is any Variant except Null then Concatenate."* but if the variant is numeric it adds! Also it says *"One expression is a numeric data type and the other is a String then A Type mismatcherror occurs."* It clearly does not it adds again! • True that it might work with 2 strings but even Microsoft recommends not to.

Comment: @federomano I cannot reproduce your issue. It always shows both values correctly. Do you have any interfering events like combobox_Change or something? Test by removing all other code from the form except the one you show.

Comment: If not something confidential, can you share the workbook in discussion? Nobody is able to reproduce the problem as you describe it...

Comment: @federomano Try to provide a [mcve]. Start a new workbook and re-built the issue so everyone can reproduce it. The code you provide in a new workbook does not show the issue.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ I added a reprex link